# Single-entry vs multiple-entry visa attending conference in Norway

Tags: schengen, norway

I will be visiting Norway this summer. I am a citizen of Bangladesh and a graduate student in the USA, and I am attending an academic conference there.

When I am filling out the application form I have several confusions. I would appreciate if somebody could help me with these issues

1. Single- vs multiple-entry
   Do I need to apply for a single- or multiple-entry visa? I will only stay in Norway. But during my flight, I may have to change planes in between Schengen countries. For example, the flight I am considering right now is from Chicago to Amsterdam to Bergen and when returning Oslo to Paris to Chicago. In that case should I apply for a multiple-entry visa or a single-entry?
2. Which Schengen country will you enter first?
   Is it Norway? I will stay in Norway but my port of entry may not be Norway.

Thanks.

Comment: The multiple entry option is for when you want to leave the Schengen zone and return to any Schengen country on the same visa. Travel from one Schengen member state to another does not require a visa (that's the entire idea of the unified visa).

Answer (score 6):

Base on what you're describing you will enter the Schengen area only once, and you only need a single-entry visa for that.

In the the itinerary you're describing, you will enter the area in Amsterdam. Flying *internally* in the Schengen area does not count as "entering" the area; you're already inside before you take that flight.

For *"Which Schengen country will you enter first?"* you should answer the actual first point of entry in the itinerary you will enclose with your application -- that is, according to your current plans, the Netherlands.

It is understood that you may change your particular travel plans after the visa is issued. As long as the trip is still recognizably the same as the one you applied for (in particular, your main destination is still the same conference in Norway) this is not a problem. The visa you get will not be tied to entering the area at a specific point, even though you stated one in the application.